# XAMPP-Magento-Error: pdo_mysql

Tags: php, magento, xampp

I'm debugging a magento-plugin with eclipse & X-Debug on a local(host) Windows-System with a portable XAMPP-environment. And because it somehow writes properly in the DB, but doesn't reads/accepts DB-Output, I've to go step-by-step through the code. 
Now eclipse started every action on the site with a long check,
`if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '<')===true) {`
so I commented that part out in a tired, weary, annoyed state of mind.

Well, eclipse didn't bother. Started 2 debugging sessions afterwards. But since closing eclipse, I get the         **`pdo_mysql extension is not installed`**     message.
All I did while using eclipse were minor changes inside the plugin. I was looking for the variable-contents. So I assumed it has to do with the     `version_compare`     and removed the comment. And if you check the error-trace below, you'll see, it never touches any (user)-plugin.

Didn't work.

Google said (in about the 50 cases I checked) either     `pdo_mysql.dll`     is commented in the     `php.ini`     or not installed. Both is not the case. The extension is activated     `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`     and all the Zend-folders exist and... it worked before.

Now I'm confused, what damage I've done and how to fix it... I don't want to set up the hole system again. Is there some kind of lock I've overseen?  Or a switch I may deactivate?

By the way: Eclipse won't start it now either.

Here's the trace:

```
Trace:
#0 [projectpath]\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#1 [projectpath]\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#2 [projectpath]\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#3 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#4 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#5 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#6 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#7 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#8 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#9 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#10 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#11 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#12 [projectpath]\app\Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#15 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#16 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#17 [projectpath]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#18 [projectpath]\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 [projectpath]\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

### Update

I checked, there are no further     `php.ini`s.  But the output of     `<?php phpinfo() ?>`       says:

```
Configure Command
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" 
"--without-pdo-mssql" 
"--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
```

Now, that     `"--without-pdo-mssql"`   would explain something. But also it's weird as there is no     `c:\php-sdk\oracle`    in any kind of way...
Oh, I guess that were the compiler-settings, **cough**

Comment: I would tend to agree with google on this one. Usually you have at least two `php.ini` files though.. one for CLI, and one for your xampp instance. Make sure that both have the extension enabled.

Comment: No, there aren't anymore     `php.ini`   files. In the     `apache\bin`    folder aren't any     `*.ini` Maybe, because it's a "portable" version, idk. Eclipse neither works as CLI nor WEB Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is absolutely unexplainable to me, but Xampp totally messed up! I hadn't touched anything there, but a bit later even phpmyadmin refused to work. Setting up the whole Xampp-Environment solved the case.

To complete the information:
I reinstalled magento (moved the magento folder to it's new destination, deleted    `app\etc\local.xml`    , created DB and opened the shop-url for installation instructions).
The plugins were integrated right from the start. I might as well had the DB restored as I have the files on disc, but I only need some sample data. Had to set up XDebug from the start. But now everything is back to normal.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are normally 2 `php.ini` files.

You need to check the one in the `apache\bin` folder.

If you checked the one in the `php\` folder that is only used by PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface )

If you cannot find the ini file then code a quick script like this and run it.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Look at the output, in the first section there is a label called `Loaded Configuration File`, that should show you where the `php.ini` file is located.

Comment: The aren't any     `*.ini`   files in     `apache\bin`    . Maybe because ist a portable version. And there are no further     `php.ini`     in the whole xampp-folder and subfolders.

Comment: See additional info on how to find your php.ini file

Comment: Loaded Configuration File  ...protableapps\xampp\php\php.ini
    Scan this dir for additional .ini files  (none)
    Additional .ini files parsed  (none)

Comment: Table: PDO support - enabled
Row: PDO drivers - no value

Answer (score 0):

For me I had PHP installed to my Windows machine along with a separate install of XAMPP which had its own version of PHP

Magento used C:/xampp/php's php.ini file, but my command line was using my separate PHP installation that I had setup in my environmental variables that was at C:/php